# Qual campo uso para armazenar um timestamp no mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso armazenar um timestamp com php, só que não sei qual seria o melhor campo do mysql para se usar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende o que você precisa armazenar, se for só a data você pode usar o tipo DATE, se for só a hora TIME e se for os dois usa DATETIME. Basta selecionar qual deles a coluna vai receber.

Comment: Eu queria armazenar um timestamp com a função time() do php

Comment: Se você que gravar time, date ou ambos atual usa o now() por exemplo insert into tabela(data)  values (now()); mas se você quer uma data especifica sugiro que utilize a função Date(); Exemplo $data = "20-01-2018";$dt  = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data[0]));

Answer (score 2):

O MySQL possui um tipo de `TIMESTAMP`, que é justamente o UNIX TIMESTAMP, [como é mencionado aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).  Uma outra opção é usar INT, já que ele é um número inteiro também.

Comment: Eu tenho a sensação de que precisa indicar um tamanho de bits quando se armazena timestamp Unix. Não lembro de isso é verdade, mas é uma sensação forte.